# Converting a layer into a forced "empty" background/mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, borders

I inherited a template from another person that has (essentially) two layers: an art background and a color filled border on top of the art. The border is a complex shape that I can't easily recreate by myself if it were to be deleted.

Is there a way to teach Photoshop that I'd like the border layer to be respected as if it were a forced "empty" layer e.g. no content, as if the content *below* the layer had been deleted? This is so that I can easily export an image that has the border content rendered transparent, but can also easily re-apply the border if I ever change my mind.

I've solved my problem in the short term by simply selecting the content inside the border, cropping to that content, and exporting once, but I don't like either having to do this multiple times, or having to save more than one .psd file.

Thanks for your help!

PS. I am rather new to Photoshop (installed it literally yesterday), so I apologize for any obvious errors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? Maybe by adding a simple example. It's not fully clear to me.

Comment: Can you simply turn off visibility for the border layer? I gotta admit.. I'm having some trouble envisioning the file construction as well.

Comment: If I am understanding your wants correctly- yes, simply turn off visibility for the border layer and export it (with no border) or turn on the border layer visibility and export it that way (with border).

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, but [knockout](https://youtu.be/l8r50aZtMhw) maybe?

Comment: Thanks @Joonas -- knockout is precisely what I was looking for. If you'd like to turn the comment into an answer, I can mark it as correct. Otherwise, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the specific scenario you have is a little lost on me, but as I suggested in the comment, [knockout](https://youtu.be/l8r50aZtMhw) can be used to basically punch through a layer or even multiple layers and it's quite commonly used with text or anything that has the potential to change.

Here's another generic example where I've given the text layer 0% fill and a shallow knockout. I also put it and the two layers I want to K.O. in a group:

[image]

**Text layer blending options:** You can get to layer blending options by right-clicking it in the layers panel and then choosing `Blending options`.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! My originally scenario is basically just literally asking for knockout -- I just had no idea it existed. (And yes, I did extensively attempt to google this. It's hard to google things as a newbie :( )