# I want to show darker image through letters

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Since im new to illustrator, i will try my best to explain the matter. I have one layer of picture behind the letters. I want to have the opacity of background picture to 30% but i want to show the same pattern of picture through the letters of opacity 100% how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case either way, but Illustrator isn't really meant for photo manipulation... I'd probably do this in Photoshop. There are many ways to do it, but you could use the knockout method: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/150329/converting-a-layer-into-a-forced-empty-background-mask/150373#150373 — But in your case the red and green layers would be a copy of the original photo and the background layer would be the original photo. Then you'd just darken the background layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do like this:
image30% + image100% on top of each other. text on top of images. select text and image100% and ctrl/cmd+7 ("Object>Clipping Mask>Make" or "right_click > make clipping mask").

If you need to have text outlined or so I suggest duplicate the text layer before clipping.

Comment: @cCristiano Cunha would it work for multiple text? if i wanted to add more then 5 letters?

Comment: yes, and the text keeps editable as well.